# ruby idiom for update or insert a hashmap

Tags: ruby, idioms

Is there a common ruby idiom for this code:

```
if hashmap.has_key?(key)
    hashmap[key] += 1
else
    hashmap[key] = 1
end
```

It feels like there might be a high order function that helps here. I'm hoping for something like

```
hashmap[key].insertOrUpdate { 1 }, {|value| value += 1}
```

**Edit:** While @Santhosh's answer is cool and works with my particular example, I am more interested in the general case. I think @sawa's answer gives the most flexibility as the code block passed in allows for complex logic like hash of hash etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then what you did, a better way is:

```
hashmap = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = 0}
```

Then you only need to do:

```
hashmap[key] += 1
```

Comment: I don't follow.  After defining `hashmap`, `hashmap['cat'] #=> 2`.

Comment: In this case the default should probably be 0 to match my example, but the general idea is good and is what I was looking for.

Comment: You can do without the block and shorten this to `hashmap = Hash.new(0)`.

Comment: Note that `Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = 0 }` will set a new key-value pair whenever you're accessing a key.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the fact that `nil.to_i` is `0`

```
hashmap[key] = hashmap[key].to_i + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) to provide a default value:

```
hashmap[key] = hashmap.fetch(key, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
hashmap = {}
key = 'cat'
hashmap[key] = (hashmap[key] || 0) + 1 #=> 1
hashmap[key] = (hashmap[key] || 0) + 1 #=> 2
```

Comment: Or `hashmap[key].to_i + 1` since `nil.to_i` is zero.

Comment: Nice, I'll have to remember that. Thanks, μ.

Comment: `nil.to_a` and `nil.to_h` are similarly useful for converting `nil`s to "empty" things.